# Filezilla is off screen

Tags: macos, filezilla

It happens quite often that the FileZilla application has menu-bar out of the screen like in attached screenshot. It is probably a bug.
I hold on `option` (or `alt`) while clicking the Window menu, and this not work for me. Please help

[there is print screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Q07x.png)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Close Filezilla

open terminal on Mac and run this command:

open -a TextEdit /Users/Yours_UserName/.config/filezilla/filezilla.xml

Find in the xml file  this row:

`<Setting name="Window position and size">-10 -100 -56 1827 1186 </Setting>`

And rewrite this in next way:

`<Setting name="Window position and size">10 10 -56 1827 1186 </Setting>`

Comment: used nano as editor, works perfectly, thanks

Comment: It also work for me!